# Bitwise Operations on Rows of lil_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I quickly extract two rows of a scipy.sparse.lil_matrix and apply bitwise operations on them? I've tried:

```
np.bitwise_and(A[1,:], A[2,:])
```

but NumPy seems to want an array type according to the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "lil_matrix", do you mean a scipy.sparse.lil_matrix?  If so, you'll have to convert your sparse array to a normal dense array to do bitwise operations on it, I believe.

```
a = np.asarray(A.todense())
np.bitwise_and(a[1,:], a[2,:])
```

Should do the trick, I think...

EDIT: Forgot an "asarray" there...

Comment: If the matrix has a lot of rows, you might want to do np.asarray(A[1,:].todense()) for each row.